ThreeJS hitbox manipulation
Very new here, apologies if this is super basic.
I have a sphere. I want to:

Be able to create zones on the mesh. So at a start there will be one zone completely around the mesh. This is essentially a hitbox
A user can have the ability to add a divider which splits the zone into two. They can move this divider ip and down the sphere, as well as tilt the angle of the divider.  The divider (which is essentially just a line on the surface of the sphere) should also be able to be manipulated such that the user can create a point in the divider and drag it down (basically making the divider curved on one side of the sphere).
The user should be able to add as many dividers as they want

How could i achieve something like this? Im also trying to use react-fiber. Not sure if that matters
I've tried creating a mesh and tried to do this by splitting a mesh but I think it might be the wrong approach

Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?
